# Icon for cancel action to distinguish from delete icon

Tags: icons, overflow

I'm dealing with a space sensitive environment where I have a Save/Cancel actions that need to be icons.  In the same area the user can also delete items, using something similar to the one in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHXP9.gif) (this can't be changed unfortunately - I would like a trash can).

What are some good options for a cancel icon that is easily distinguishable from the delete icon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any actionable icon without descriptive text is probably a bad idea, just because it leads to confusion like this. Though, the most common icon I've seen for "cancel", besides the red X, is the "No" symbol:

[image]

(Source: http://iconfinder.net/data/icons/c9d/cancel.png)

Comment: Agreed. Alas I cannot fit text on the screen in this case.  I'll use different shades of red, and have a tooltip, so I'll call that good enough.  Thanks!

Comment: Often on Mac the delete icon used in toolbars are a circle with a slash through. Using it for cancel may confuse Mac users if they are used to it meaning delete.

Comment: @neoneye: I think this is bound to confuse some users in any case...

Answer (score 3):

The only things that I can think of given your constraints are either a circle with a slash through it (a la no smoking signs) or a back arrow if something like that makes sense in your UI.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but Russell's linked pic has the same idea, and he answered first - so I accepted his.

Answer (score 3):

Can your save/cancel actions be translated as commit/abort? If so, you could pick some icons that are further away from the traditional save/cancel iconography.

Comment: Not really.  Good thought though. I'll keep it in mind for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

A **trashcan** might be unambiguously "delete" instead of "cancel".

Answer (score 2):

If the "cancelling" action could reasonable be reframed as a "closing" action, then you may have a few more choices. There are some very familiar icons used to "Close" parts of a user interface, including on the browser window you're using now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the file icon and overlay the cancel button suggested by RussellUresti on top.